# Triggering an animation alongside another one during scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I'm having a little bit of a problem here.

As you can see, my code triggers an animation where my `box` moves `100px` from my left to my right when I scroll over 1/3 of the height of the `section-one` div.

As you can see, in the `box` there is a `line` div which grows from `0px` to `100px`.

Here comes the catch: I want the `line` transition to trigger alongside with my `box` element. Currently this doesn't happen. If I wait more than `2s`, which is the `animation-duration` of `line`, the animations is finished by the time the `box` div pops up on screen.

Bellow I've attached my code and here is a [link](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/wjdMLQ) to my Codepen.

Jade

```
.landing-page
.section-one
  .box.hidden
    .line
```

SASS

```
@mixin box()
  position: absolute
  width: 50%
  height: 50%
  background: red
.landing-page
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  background: gray
.section-one
  position: relative
  height: 100vh
  width: 50vw
  background: lightblue
  display: flex
  justify-content: end
  align-items: center
  .box
    @include box()
    transition: 2000ms
    .line
      background: white
      height: 20px
      transition: 2000ms
      animation-name: test
      animation-duration: 2s
      animation-fill-mode: forwards
  .box.hidden
    opacity: 0
    transform: translateX(-100px)

@keyframes test
  0%
    width: 0px
  100%
    width: 100px
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var aboutEl = $('.box'),
        aboutElOffset = aboutEl.offset().top/3,
        documentEl = $(document);

    documentEl.on('scroll', function () {
        if (documentEl.scrollTop() > aboutElOffset && aboutEl.hasClass('hidden')) aboutEl.removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply apply the animation when you remove the class *(check comment in code)*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aboutEl = $('.box'),
    aboutElOffset = aboutEl.offset().top / 3,
    documentEl = $(document);

  documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
    if (documentEl.scrollTop() > aboutElOffset && aboutEl.hasClass('hidden')) aboutEl.removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.landing-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: gray;
}

.section-one {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.section-one .box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  transition: 2000ms;
}

.section-one .box .line {
  background: white;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 2000ms;
  /*remove it from here 
  animation-name: test;*/
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/*Apply animation when there is no hidden*/
.section-one .box:not(.hidden) .line {  
  animation-name: test;
}

.section-one .box.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-page"></div>
<div class="section-one">
  <div class="box hidden">
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use transition for the white element as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aboutEl = $('.box'),
    aboutElOffset = aboutEl.offset().top / 3,
    documentEl = $(document);

  documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
    if (documentEl.scrollTop() > aboutElOffset && aboutEl.hasClass('hidden')) aboutEl.removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.landing-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: gray;
}

.section-one {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.section-one .box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  transition: 2000ms;
}

.section-one .box .line {
  background: white;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 2s;
  width:0px;
}
.section-one .box:not(.hidden) .line {  
  width:100px;
}

.section-one .box.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-page"></div>
<div class="section-one">
  <div class="box hidden">
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you!